# Stuck at GRUB after PXE Boot-System

Tags: boot, grub2, pxe

I installed ubuntu 16.04 on a headless server, it goes to the PXE Boot-system screen of my provider, starts local boot by default then I'm stuck at a GRUB command, but I cannot type anything. When I'm pressing keys (a-z), it just adds more arrows and pressing enter doesn't do anything.

[image]

However, there is no problem booting in vkvm mode.
What can I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you're working with one of their LARA consoles. I once got one where I could not type anything either, the replacement fixed that problem. If you couldn't type *anything* in the session, reply to the ticket saying that the LARA does not accept keyboard input.

The line `boot: l` indicates that the box tried to boot from the local hard disk. And that's the point where things start getting weird, as "PXE" after "local" indicates that nothing bootable could be found.

Try using Hetzner's rescue system, which will get their boxes online if the hardware is still good. If the box boots into rescue, you should be able to connect via ssh and check the contents of the hard disk.

Alternative: Use the robot interface to re-install ubuntu and if that does not work, submit a ticket to have their support look at the problem.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Indeed, it was not finding anything bootable because for some reason the secondary disk took priority on the first when they replaced a defective drive. With the LARA console, I managed to access the UEFI and fix that. Weird thing though is that the system was booting correctly in vkvm mode...